# Updating partially a blob or binary type in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, binary, blob, bit-manipulation

I am currently involved in a project that requires to store a chunk of bits in a column of a table on MySQL. Originally, the type of the column was MySQL BIT, and I was able to do for example something like:

```
UPDATE table SET column = column | b'0001'
```

in order to set a bit 1 in the column in a certain position.

However, because of the limitation of the size (maximum 64 bits), and due requeriments of the project, I have tried to find another column type, like a BLOB, or BINARY that allows us to achieve something like what I exposed in the example.

So, the question is: how can be set a certain bit in the value of a column in MySQL?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I'd use varchar as type and a stored procedure for that.

Comment: can you elaborate your answer? Thansk!